# What is meant by a "Penny in the slot reaction"

Tags: phrases

What is meant by a penny-in-the-slot reaction?

Context: In a discussion of meditation, one benefit was described as "Less penny-in-the-slot reactions and more true choice."

Comment: Where did you read or hear this? What is the broader context, and what have your researches discovered that you didn't understand?

Comment: Based on the replies below, it appears that some context is needed to make a reasonable guess at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Penny-in-the-slot refers to something machine like.
So in the context mentioned, it means mediation helps lessen the mechanical or machine like(penny-in-the-slot) reactions and helps make true choices.

Mechanical/ machine like reactions - Following set rules, with no room for change or deviation. Basically not being open to different perceptions and possibilities.

Comment: Do you have a source or relevant information to back-up your answer?

Answer (score 0):

A "penny-in-the-slot reaction" looks very much like a derivative of **the penny dropped** which is British English to exclaim that something has suddenly been understood as in, *"She looked confused for a moment, then suddenly the penny dropped"* (Cambridge Dictionary).

I sense that the "penny dropped" is itself a derivative of to "*spend a penny"* (a polite phrase to urinate - Cambridge Dictionary), a British English euphemism for expressing the need to urinate and/or defecate, as in, *I need to spend a penny. Let's stop at the next motorway service station.* In turn, this euphemism must surely harken back to the early-to-mid 20th century era in the UK (and British Empire/Commonwealth) when one had to put a penny-in-the-slot (a shiny brass lock mechanism) to open a cubicle's door in an urban public lavatory - hence "spend a penny" - hence the OP's "penny-in-the-slot reaction" which infers the instant sense of relief that one would surely garner from gaining entrance to the lavatory. I sense that this analogy invites us to conclude that in the context of the OP, a person's action should not governed by a very pressing need to do it but rather by a free choice to do it or not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the 19th century there was a proliferation of mechanical banks where a coin would be held by a slot, and the machine did a spring powered action to put the coin in the bank.

[One example](http://m.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Iron-Mechanical-Bank-Station-H1-Nice-/112132021850?_trkparms=aid%253D222007%2526algo%253DSIC.MBE%2526ao%253D1%2526asc%253D20150519202348%2526meid%253D7a17eb378d02472ea7208e1babe7620c%2526pid%253D100408%2526rk%253D3%2526rkt%253D10%2526sd%253D122130272631&_trksid=p2056116.c100408.m2460)

[Another example](http://m.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Cast-Iron-Mechanical-Clown-Bank-Reproduction-Works-Perfectly-/252537257655?hash=item3acc64beb7%3Ag%3AAUUAAOSwGtRX10rW&_trkparms=pageci%3D62c6fdf1-49a0-422a-a932-63f01f1b2b0d%2Cparentrq%3D2d9353381570a866df651706fff8ee14%2Ciid%3D1%2Cobjectid%3D885)

There's only one cause and effect, no choices.